# How to perform step-wise expansion of a C preprocessor macro?

Tags: c-preprocessor

`gdb` has a documented, yet still unimplemented command (as of version 8.3) called `macro expand-once`.  Its purpose is to perform a single-step macro expansion without recursing into other macro invocations.  From the [docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html):

> `macro expand-once`*`expression`*
>   `macro exp1`*`expression`*
>
> *(This command is not yet implemented.)* Show the results of expanding those preprocessor macro invocations that appear explicitly in *expression*. Macro invocations appearing in that expansion are left unchanged. This command allows you to see the effect of a particular macro more clearly, without being confused by further expansions. Since `GDB` simply expands macros, but does not parse the result, *expression* need not be a valid expression; it can be any string of tokens.

What an excruciating tease!  Such a feature would lay the groundwork for a conceptually simple, iterative `gdb` script to output each step of a macro expansion, which is exactly the information I am seeking.  Whether or not it happens to be delivered by `gdb` is secondary to me, but I do want this to be automated somehow — I am tired of digging through code and writing everything out by hand.

Until the `macro expand-once` command of `gdb` is implemented, is there some other programmatic way to perform step-wise expansion of a C preprocessor macro?  I imagine it might be possible by dumping macro definitions from `cpp`, parsing the output, and making a sort of "call graph", but maybe I'm being naively optimistic.

**NOTE**: Although the bounty note states, "Simply providing references to library functions for constructing a potential solution will not be rewarded the bounty," I may still accept such an answer if a bounty-qualifying solution has not been posted by the end of the bounty period.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`wave`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/wave/) (part of the boost library):

Example from the [documenation:](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/wave/doc/tracing_facility.html)

File `test.cpp`:

```
    // test.cpp
    #define X(x)          x
    #define Y()           2
    #define CONCAT_(x, y) x ## y
    #define CONCAT(x, y)  CONCAT_(x, y)
    #pragma wave trace(enable)
    // this macro expansion is to be traced
    CONCAT(X(1), Y())     // should expand to 12
    #pragma wave trace(disable)
```

Running `wave -t test.trace test.cpp` creates a file `test.trace`:

```
test.cpp:8:1: CONCAT(X(1), Y())
  test.cpp:5:9: see macro definition: CONCAT(x, y)
  invoked with
  [
    x = X(1)
    y = Y()
  ]
  [
    test.cpp:2:9: see macro definition: X(x)
    invoked with
    [
      x = 1
    ]
    [
      1
      rescanning
      [
        1
      ]
    ]
    test.cpp:3:9: see macro definition: Y()
    [
      2
      rescanning
      [
        2
      ]
    ]
    CONCAT_(1, 2)
    rescanning
    [
      test.cpp:4:9: see macro definition: CONCAT_(x, y)
      invoked with
      [
        x = 1
        y = 2
      ]
      [
        12
        rescanning
        [
          12
        ]
      ]
      12
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [repository history](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;f=gdb/macrocmd.c;h=6821892ed4f6f609e09b137d7163c712ded7a0be), here is an excerpt from the `ChangeLog`, which dates back to 2002:

> 2002-05-16  Jim Blandy
>
> Add commands for manually expanding macros and showing their
>   definitions.

However, it appears that it was never followed up on.

Per the [GCC Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html),

> Macro expansion is a tricky operation, fraught with nasty corner cases and situations that render what you thought was a nifty way to optimize the preprocessor’s expansion algorithm wrong in quite subtle ways.

Perhaps this is why it was never implemented?

> The preprocessor stores macro expansions in tokenized form. This saves repeated lexing passes during expansion, at the cost of a small increase in memory consumption on average. The tokens are stored contiguously in memory, so a pointer to the first one and a token count is all you need to get the replacement list of a macro.

In theory, it would be possible to step through each token via pointer arithmetic; however, if it were so simple then I cannot imagine why it has not already been implemented.

Comment: "In theory, it would be possible to step through each token via pointer arithmetic; however, if it were so simple then I cannot imagine why it has not already been implemented." Seems like a question worthy of the mailing list. Sometime over the holidays, I'll post there and report back.

Comment: I posted on the mailing list ~10 days ago but haven't gotten a response.

Comment: Can you include a link from the archives?

Comment: I never know how much detail to include when posting to a mailing list, so it's pretty minimal. Maybe the tone was off, which is why I didn't get a response. Here it is: https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2019-12/msg00058.html