Using clang-format to replace function-like macros?
I am currently maintaining an older C++ codebase that is full of function-like macros like these:
#define rnd(x) ((int)(randomMT()&0x7FFFFFFF)%(x))
#define rndscale(x) (float((randomMT()&0x7FFFFFFF)*double(x)/double(0x7FFFFFFF)))
#define detrnd(s, x) ((int)(((((uint)(s))*1103515245+12345)>>16)%(x)))

#define loop(v,m) for(int v = 0; v < int(m); ++v)
#define loopi(m) loop(i,m)
#define loopj(m) loop(j,m)
#define loopk(m) loop(k,m)
#define loopl(m) loop(l,m)
#define looprev(v,m) for(int v = int(m); --v >= 0;)
#define loopirev(m) looprev(i,m)
#define loopjrev(m) looprev(j,m)
#define loopkrev(m) looprev(k,m)
#define looplrev(m) looprev(l,m)

#define DELETEP(p) if(p) { delete   p; p = 0; }
#define DELETEA(p) if(p) { delete[] p; p = 0; }

Which then are used like this:
void initparticles()
{
    if(initing) return;
    if(!particleshader) particleshader = lookupshaderbyname("particle");
    if(!particlenotextureshader) particlenotextureshader = lookupshaderbyname("particlenotexture");
    if(!particlesoftshader) particlesoftshader = lookupshaderbyname("particlesoft");
    if(!particletextshader) particletextshader = lookupshaderbyname("particletext");
    loopi(sizeof(parts)/sizeof(parts[0])) parts[i]->init(parts[i]->type&PT_FEW ? min(fewparticles, maxparticles) : maxparticles);
    loopi(sizeof(parts)/sizeof(parts[0]))
    {
        loadprogress = float(i+1)/(sizeof(parts)/sizeof(parts[0]));
        parts[i]->preload();
    }
    loadprogress = 0;
}

I believe those make the code hard to read and hard to maintain. I tried using clang-format to replace those macros, but it did not seem to have an option to replace the macros with their code. What is the most effective way of replacing those macros with their normal code?

related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019609/any-utility-to-test-expand-c-c-define-macros

That'd be more of a job for clang-tidy than format but i don't think it has this feature either

You could run just the preprocessor and then use the generated output to replaced the formerly macro-ified code with the post-processed code.  If it is a lot of files with this heavy macro usage, it could be quite a bit of manual bother.

Just replacing the macros will not fix the real issues. Like manual memory managment. My first question would be : do you have unit tests? If not maybe it's just better to leave most of the code as is, and only refactor when you need to bugfix code or add features.

No unit tests. I've introduced a few e2e tests to help me not destroy everything, but that's about it.
